# How can I achieve a more upstream GNOME 3.4 desktop?

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install the full Gnome 3 desktop in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119357/how-to-install-the-full-gnome-3-desktop-in-ubuntu)

When using Ubuntu 12.04 and gnome-shell I feel that I am being cheated out of the wonderful experience that is Gnome. To better understand try Fedora 17. My question is basically how do I achieve a more Vanilla Gnome 3 Desktop. The main differences are in the subtle things actually, the overall look of the theme, the control center, etc. I think however I may have answered my own question by doing some additional research. I think that some of the things I like may actually be Fedora features and some of the thing that are missing may be because for whatever reason Ubuntu didn't upgrade all packages to 3.4 but only some. I am currently installing updates after adding the gnome team ppa and I am hoping this will do the trick.