# Hitting Screenshot key does not give a preview

Tags: 12.04, screenshot, previews

Back on 11.10, whenever I would take a screenshot, there would be a preview that gave me the option to either copy to a clipboard, save image wherever I wanted to, or cancel (in case I bumped the PrntScrn key by accident).

But, I'm on 12.04 and that option seems to be gone. Whenever I press PrntScrn, it does the typical sound and flash, but I don't get the preview. I originally thought that this option was removed from Ubuntu, but whenever I was helping my brother on his new 12.04 install, I found that the key gives the preview on his computer. He has a brand new 12.04 install, but I have a 12.04 install that was upgraded from 11.10.

Does anyone have any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: Are you, perchance, on Gnome-Shell (or some other DE that's not Unity)? If so, see [Where is the print screen dialogue?](http://askubuntu.com/q/118573/8724).

Comment: I'm on Unity. Is your link non-unity only?

Comment: Yes—it says that not showing the dialogue is the correct behaviour in GS, but it is supposed to be shown in Unity. Just thought I'd ask.

Comment: Sounds like what happens when you press Ctrl+Print - screenshots gets copied to the clipboard directly (you can paste it into GIMP then, for instance). Did you check System Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts? Possibly something went wrong there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your configuration. Go to "System Settings" > "Keyboard"

[image]

Then go to "Shortcuts" > "Screenshots"

[image]