# How can I capture keystroke “print screen” in Gnome 3?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't the PrintScreen dialog show up in Gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118573/why-doesnt-the-printscreen-dialog-show-up-in-gnome)

Have sound indicating “picture was taking – a click sound” but do not have any file to examine – where is it?

Answer (score 0):

If your system is configured so that taking screenshots doesn't give you a dialog box where you see a preview and decide where to save the file, then it is probably saving them to whatever location is set as the default.

The **Pictures** folder directly inside your home folder is the most likely default location, unless you've changed it.

Comment: Eliah Kagan, thank you for your answer - I found them in folder "/home/username/Bilder" (Swedish Ubuntu 12.04).