# How to PRINT a screen using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, printing, shortcuts

Since Windows 95 I have used Alfred Bollinger's PrintKey program to print what is on the screen. I have just started Ubuntu and can not find a keyboard shortcut that will let me PRINT what is on the screen. Although sometimes it is nice to save a copy of the screen, I want to just print what is on my screen whether it is using FireFox, or just the desktop. Please is there some way to map the  key to print? Do you all know of a program that would work with UBuntu and do this?

Reply: (I still haven't figured out yet how to get the comments up so will do it here)
Thank You all.  I will try the various suggestions until I find one that fits me.  I believed there had to be a way to redefine the keys, but don't  have enough knowledge yet of Ubuntu.  I'll post which one works best for me when I decide. Thanks again.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If you press the Print Screen key on your keyboard Ubuntu will save an image of the screen in your Pictures directory.

Comment: that ^^ and one of the programs that rock when taking pixs: shutter.

Comment: What I have been accustomed to is to press the PrtScn button and have a copy of the screen sent to the printer. With both Windows and Ubuntu, PrtScn button sends a copy to the clipboard. I want a way to change this behavior and send a print to the printer. Below are some good suggestions that I intend to try.

Answer (score 1):

In "system settings" go to "Keyboard" ==> "Shortcuts" and then click on "Screenshots" and now you can edit what ever key you like to be your "screenshot key"
have fun

Answer (score 0):

Shutter will do the job. To install shutter open the terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) and type/paste these text :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

To make shutter as your default print screen program [read this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252717/how-to-make-shutter-as-the-default-screenshot-tool)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an additional shortcut to just send the full screen to your default printer:

First install the package ´imagemagick`.

Then open the System Settings and click the "Keyboard" symbol in the "Hardware" section. Open the "Shortcuts" tab, click on "Custom Shortcuts" on the left and on the "+" button at the bottom:

[image: add custom keyboard shortcut]

This will open a small dialog with a "Name" and a "Command" input line. Choose something like "Print screen" for the name and

```
sh -c 'import -window root png:-| lp'
```

for the command:

[image: shortcut dialog]

Then click "Apply". In the list you see your new shortcut with the word `Disabled` on the right:

[image: shortcut list]

Click on the word `Disabled` and it will change to `New accelerator...`. Now press the key combo you want for this shortcut. Now you can use that combo to make a full screen print.

Note that it doesn't ask any questions and doesn't give any feedback but silently prints your screen to your default printer.

Comment: Why not use the pre-configured `Screenshots` option [3rd option from top] and simply customize both shortcuts there?

Comment: Sometimes he/she may want to save a screenshot to a file

Comment: For me it does exactly that: 'Take Screenshot', followed by 'Save Screenshot' option, in form of two dialog windows!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gnome on ubuntu 20.04 :
Quickly take a screenshot of the desktop, a window, or an area at any time using these global keyboard shortcuts:

```
Prt Scrn to take a screenshot of the desktop.

Alt+Prt Scrn to take a screenshot of a window.

Shift+Prt Scrn to take a screenshot of an area you select.
```

When you use a keyboard shortcut, the image is automatically saved in your Pictures folder in your home folder with a file name that begins with Screenshot and includes the date and time it was taken.

If you do not have a Pictures folder, the images will be saved in your home folder instead.

for further info: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/screen-shot-record.html.en