# How to change the keyboard shortcut to take screenshots with Shutter?

Tags: shortcut-keys, screenshot, shutter

I use Shutter for screenshots. When I press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, a popup appears that a screenshot is going to be made in 2 seconds. After that Shutter opens, and I can then crop the image directly to the relevant part, which is for me the real bonus of this program.

However, I don't like the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> keybinding as this is used in other programs for redo, so I want to disable or change that to another combination.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Shutter as the default screenshot tool?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252717/how-to-make-shutter-as-the-default-screenshot-tool)

Comment: Not a duplicate. It has no answer to the keybinding and opening Shutter after pressing the PRT SCR key.

Comment: Did you read the answer?

Comment: Yes I did and I changed the settings using Compiz. I've updated my question to the part that is not fixed.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could update if the answer I gave works for you or not.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You may use the Custom Shortcuts available in Keyboard Settings to capture screenshots using Shutter with different key combinations.

Open System Settings and click on *Keyboard*.

[image: System Settings Window - click on Keyboard]

Next, switch to the *Shortcuts* tab, select *Custom Shortcuts* in the sidepanel and click on the + icon to add a new one. In the dialog that pops up, give a *name* so that you would be able to quickly recognize it later on and the *command* which you wish to run when the keyboard shortcut gets activated; and click *Apply*.

I have put "Snap with Shutter" as Name and `shutter -f` as the Command. (`shutter -f` captures the full screen, for other available commands, refer to `CAPTURE MODE OPTIONS` given in `man shutter`.)

[image: Add custom shortcut]

This would create an entry with the name you provided and shortcut as "Disabled" (since you haven't yet provided one to it). To bind a shortcut to it, click on the "Disabled" text and hit the shortcut keys you would wish to bind to it. It it succeeds, the key combination would be visible to you, otherwise it would ask you to provide an another one.

[image: Custom shortcut entry - click on "Disabled" to provide one]

Comment: I would like to make a shortcut for capture AREA of screen. How can I do this?

Comment: Use "shutter -s" instead of shutter -f

Comment: Just toadd: also works under UBUNTU-mate 16.04: `control center` → `keyboards shortcuts` and there 'custom' expandable there... what a time saver! ❤

Comment: To get a list of options available, type `shutter --help` on the terminal.