# How to get the default screenshot tool?

Tags: command-line, screenshot

I want to get user's default screenshooter application. Like, in a fresh install Ubuntu, it is `gnome-screenshot`, or in Xubuntu it is `xfce4-screenshooter`. Or maybe Distro A's screenshooter is `imagemagick`'s import, I don't know.

How can I check this?

I'm trying to test whether the user has a screenshooter, a screen capture utility. If so, I'll use it and capture screen, for example.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

To get the name of the default screenshot tool from terminal you can use the following command:

```
gsettings get org.compiz.integrated command-screenshot
```

Otherwise, this [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/252717/147044) may help you.

Comment: So simple, +1 for gsettings

Comment: is this global? i mean, universal. uhm... is this valid in gnome only?

Answer (score 0):

On the different Ubuntu flavors you can use the following command to get the name of the default screenshooter application:

```
egrep -l -H "(applets-screenshooter|snapshot)" /usr/share/applications/* | grep -oP "^.*/\K(.*?)(?=\.desktop)"
```

This command looks for desktop applications with the `snapshot` keyword or the `applets-screenshooter` icon and outputs only the desktop file name (without the extension).

To use the output for example in a `bash` script:

```
$ screenshooter="$(egrep -l -H "(applets-screenshooter|snapshot)" /usr/share/applications/* | grep -oP "^.*/\K(.*?)(?=\.desktop)")"
$ echo $screenshooter
gnome-screenshot
```

Comment: I'm sure that my default screenshoter is *Shutter*. Even like this, your answer give me another two default screenshooters (gnome-screenshot and xfce4-screenshooter). How can be this possible? To have two default screenshooters?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Actually I assumed that my command had to be run on a fresh installation. I then checked the `.desktop` files of gnome-terminal, KSnapshot and xfce4-screenshooter. As shutter is not installed by default I didn't check it. Of course if you install xfce4-screenshooter on stock ubuntu it will also match hence the two results.