# Print Screen key doesn't work

Tags: unity, keyboard

I have an HP pavilion 15 notebook running Ubuntu 17.04. The "print screen" key on the keyboard meant to take screenshots doesn't work. How can I get it to work?

Comment: Have you tried holding FN while pressing it?

Comment: Yes I have. It still doesn't work

Comment: Take a look into System Settings > keyboard > Screenshots

Comment: I did. The command there says "print". In fact none of the "print" combinations work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to install [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/), an excelent screenshot tool.

Open a terminal session and install it:

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

and assign [PrtSc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252717/how-to-make-shutter-as-the-default-screenshot-tool) shortcut to it. I use it, it's great!!