# Print screen key not working on Lubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: lubuntu, shutter, print-screen

I recently installed Lubuntu 20.04.1 which runs with LXQt. I tried to take a picture of my desktop using the Print screen key. However, it is not working. Nothing happens.

I found a post mentioning [shutter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952054/print-screen-key-doesnt-work) but when adding the ppa repository and executing the `sudo apt install shutter` command I get a permission confirmation to install around 96 new packets. That's how shutter is coded to run on gnome and I'm afraid to install all those packets and create conflicts with LXQt.

Is there a way to fix the Print screen key issue without installing any program on Lubuntu 20.04.1?

Comment: Have you logged in using *Lubuntu* or *LXQt*, as PrintScreen should operate correctly when you log in with the *Lubuntu* session (*without any change*). LXQt is provided for a purer upstream experience, and some expected keys won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt install deepin-screenshot
```

then go to *Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcus* choose *Add Custom Shortcut*

In command enter `deepin-screenshot` and name it *screenshot* for example.

And assign any key combination you like.