# Quick image uploading program? (Ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: gnome, nautilus, clipboard, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I'm slowly migrating to Ubuntu 20.10 from a (brief) lifetime of Windows, and enjoying the transition. I'm more fond of GNOME than I expected.

One tool I've been missing is puush, which is a Windows/MacOS/Android program that allows you to take a (cropped) screenshot and immediately upload it, and then insert the image URL into your clipboard. It can do this from your clipboard (if you've copied an image), from a cursor select (accessed through a keybind), or even from Windows Explorer (through the right-click context menu).

I'm currently using GNOME's native screenshot feature, which does half of what I need perfectly well- taking a cropped snapshot via `Shift + PrtSc` and saving it to my Pictures file. However, I would like to have a quick method of uploading this to an image sharing website and sharing the URL to the image.

I'd like such a program to be up-to-date (i.e. unlike Shutter if possible, if not, fine), and I'd be the happiest if I could use it through the overhead notification/status bar, Files/Nautilus, or a keybind.

What are my options? I'm also open to a more cohesive program that does the screenshotting for me as well.

Comment: In  *my opinion*, Shutter is going to be your best choice. Also, I use *Lubuntu* so it's a bit different for me. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252717/how-to-make-shutter-as-the-default-screenshot-tool) is old, but you can integrate Shutter with your OS, making it work with keyboard shortcuts. And, well, Shutter may be a bit older - but it works. You will need to tinker with it to get the editing function to work, but there are may tutorials online for that. Invest the time once and just keep good backups.

Comment: I installed Shutter from snapcraft.io and it works well! Not as quick as puush, but it's still quick and convenient; and I also like that I can access it quickly from the overhead bar.

Comment: Spectacle has some of these features.  Spectacle is the screenshot utility for the KDE desktop, but you should be able to install it on GNOME as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Shutter as a snap (?) from [this link](https://snapcraft.io/shutter), and it installed without any problems. I'm satisfied with it.