# Where are (partial) screenshot stored or how to specifiy location?

Tags: print-screen

When I use the print screen key - PrtSc - I get the option of where to save.  That works fine.

However when I shift-ctrl-PrtSc I hear the picture being 'taken' but I don't get a chance to specify the location.

I have checked the following locations and they do NOT have the screenshot:

```
My Desktop
My Documents
My home directory
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As I know holding **Ctrl** copies the screenshot to the **clipboard** and you need to paste it in an application to save it.

You can check the shortcut keys in Keyboard Settings.

[image: Screenshot shortcuts]

Answer (score 14):

I played around some more and found that using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> will copy the window only and then give me the option of where to save.

2014 - Update

<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> - Capture the entire screen (all windows) and ask where to save
<kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> - Capture the currently focused window and ask where to save
<kbd>Shift</kbd>  <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> - Select specific area for capture and ask where to save

Comment: I am used to using `alt`+`print` method. But, do you know how to change it's default save folder?
I tried to configure it in dconf-editor, I set the `auto-save-directory` of gnome-screenshot to specified location. But, it doesn't work. It still saves the captured picture in `My Pictures` folder.

Comment: It isn't like you said (".. and then give me the option of where to save."). It's automatically save the picture to `My Pictures` folder. And oh, I was using gnome desktop instead of unity.

Comment: A bit late, you can use this command `gnome-screenshot --interactive` in terminal to open gnome-screenshot graphic interface. I suggest to make an alias in your `~/.bashrc` (e.g. `alias screenshot="gnome-screenshot --interactive"`)

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> is a better way, as you will be prompted for where to save the screenshot (and by what filename).

Comment: Dude!  Thank you for teaching me how to use the kbd tag for those icons.  Now let me try it in a comment:  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> - Nope.  Doesn't work here.  But that is great to know.

Comment: Eliah Kagan Thanks for your edit, it helps me for better understanding (for English and Stackoverflow :D)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, no prompt. Simply saved.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple answer to your direct question(s):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> will copy the whole screen to the clipboard. It is not saved on disk.

To get a partial, you add <kbd>Shift</kbd>, whether you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (clipboard) or not (save and/or clipboard).

---

Of course, you probably know that just pressing <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> will capture the whole screen and give you the options to save to clipboard and/or save it to disk, with a default directory of ~/Pictures

Answer (score 1):

try using Shutter instead, It's awesome:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa    
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install shutter
```

However I think you can also try this not sure if it will fix that exactly:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory to 
file:///home/yourusername/wherever/you/want
```

you can also use get to see where it is suppose to be saving them:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-screenshot
```

Source: [Why doesn't the PrintScreen dialog show up in Gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118573/why-doesnt-the-printscreen-dialog-show-up-in-gnome)