# xmodmap stops working when switching in-between tty sessions

Tags: xorg, shortcut-keys

I have made a keybinding with xmodmap `keysym Alt_R = Pointer_Button1`, and enabled it with `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`.

The keybinding works fine. However if I temporarily switch to another tty session and switch back, the keybinding stops working. And I need to enable it again.

What could be causing this? And is it possible to fix this somehow?

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Did you find a workaround ?

Comment: @RémyHosseinkhanBoucher Unfortunately not. I put the code into a script and settled for rerunning it each time I switch back from a different session.

Comment: Hi @Lenny White, I used to use xmodmap like you, but it is deprecated ! A few days ago I found a better solution for this kind of problem please see my answer here and tell me what do you think of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/976748/how-to-change-prtsc-key-to-right-click-in-ubuntu-17-10/1219481#1219481

It does persist when switching tty, you just have to found the equivalent key switching !

Comment: @RémyHosseinkhanBoucher Hey thanks a lot man! Didn't know it was deprecated. So I guess I should edit the xkb file. Could you help me with the equivalent command for `keysym Alt_R = Pointer_Button1`?

Comment: So you want your AltGr key to be 'Pointer_Button1' ? Hence I guess we need to find the **keycode** associated to 'Pointer_Button1' ?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/336674/emulating-mouse-click-with-a-keyboard, I've run 'xkbevd' and I found that right click has keycode 1 on my laptop, could you try keysym Alt_R = 1 in the evdev file ?

Comment: @RémyHosseinkhanBoucher Sorry I'm not familiar with the structure of this file, where do I add this line?

Comment: On my laptop I have a <RALT> = 108: line in the /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev file, try to replace 108 by 1  and reboot ?

Comment: @RémyHosseinkhanBoucher I'll try this out thanks!