# How do I launch gnome's print screen dialog without using the PrtScn key in recent versions of Gnome?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, lenovo, 22.04, screenshot

I use a laptop from linovo where they replaced the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key with <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>. I restored the menu key through XKB - which fortunately still works with Wayland Gnome - but lost the dedicated print-screen key as a result. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976748/how-to-change-prtsc-key-to-menu-in-ubuntu-17-10) for a picture of the problem.

To get around the lack of a <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> key, I used to run `gnome-screenshot -i` from the terminal. Unfortunately, this command was removed in whatever version of Gnome that shipped with Ubuntu 22.04. I tried guessing the command in Gnome's "Run a Command" dialog (i.e <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>`) with little success.

How do access the screenshot functionality in modern versions of gnome without using the dedicated keyboard key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next to the [option you found yourself](https://askubuntu.com/a/1411412/558158), there is another way. You can reassign the keybindings to take a screenshot in "Settings", "Keyboard", then "View and Customize shortcuts. You will find a "Screenshots" section there, where you can change the default keybindings to something else.

In Ubuntu 22.04, screenshots is not anymore a separate tool. It is a function integrated in the code of Gnome Shell itself (very much like Gnome Shell extensions also integrate into the Gnome Shell code).

Comment: I was pleasantly surprised to find that setting a custom shortcut does indeed work in Gnome. Thank you so much for this suggestion. This is exactly what I was hoping for!

Answer (score 2):

Typing "*screenshot*" in Gnome's Start Menu - the screen that appears when you press the windows keys - did the trick.

Comment: confirmed working for me on 23.04