# Are there any 32-bit versions of screen recording sofware for Ubuntu 18.04 that you would recommend?

Tags: 18.04, software-recommendation, 32-bit, desktop-recording

I need to find a desktop screen recording software (preferably free) that I can use on a 32 bit Ubuntu Linux laptop. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: If the CPU is 32bit, the only OS you can install is 32bit, and then all packages will be 32bit, screen recorders included.

Comment: I understand. This thread was actually for recommendations though, as I am sure others have the same question..

Comment: Recommendations was not what you've asked for. You'll easily find multiple entries, if search for "ubuntu screen recorders". In case that's a problem, here is a search link: https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=ubuntu%20screen%20recordeers

Comment: Your right thank you very much for the help. I've decided upon OBS. I had it in the past but it didn't work. Ah I just installed it now from here: https://obsproject.com/download. My problem is this "Failed to initialize video.  Your GPU may not be supported, or your graphics drivers may need to be updated.", in the past the screen would go completely black which I assumed was the gpu crashing. Anyways that's a different problem. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Also I just updated the question. Your comment is sure to come in handy for someone else too.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 provides a buildin screencast feature. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1145343/77093

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Screenshot tool bundled with Gnome does exactly what you described
It can sreencast too

Screenshot pictures are saved in you default Pictures directory
`xdg-user-dir PICTURES`

**Screencast** videos are saved in the home Video directory
`xdg-user-dir VIDEOS`

Screenshots:
<kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> to take a screenshot of the desktop.
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> to take a screenshot of a window.
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> to take a screenshot of an area you select.

**Screencasts**:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> starts recording the desktop.
A red circle is displayed in the top right corner of the screen when the recording is in progress.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> stops the recording.

Please read the manual:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html.en#screenshot

Comment: Thank you! Haha I should have mentioned I am actually running Lubuntu. But this will come in handy when I install Ubuntu on my other laptop! I am going to try to get it to work on this laptop as well after I figure out what my gpu is and how to update it. I am looking for methods to find out my gpu without installing anything. Also it would definitely be nice to be able to screencast without downloading anything too.  I would upvote this answer if I could. Thanks again for the info.

Comment: @w3Develops : to get gpu info, run `sudo lshw -C display`

Comment: Thanks again! I found this before but didn't know if what I was looking at was correct. Now that you've confirmed this, it seems simple.

```description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
```

Again I would upvote if I could.