# Is there a setting to turn off the dialog box when making screenshots?

Tags: 14.04, gnome-screenshot

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/118579/261938), pressing the screenshot hotkey will do either of 2 things:

1. For Unity users, it'll open the dialog box where you can set the picture's name, location and whether or not it'll be copied to clipboard instead.
2. For Gnome users, it'll automatically save the picture with a name that shows time and date taken to the set autosave folder (`~/Pictures` by default).

I've been using gnome-flashback (formerly known as Gnome Classic (No Effects) or Gnome Fallback) for a long time and have had the second outcome happen every time. For some reason, though, after upgrading to 14.04 and switching Unity to gnome-flashback, it started doing the first one instead.

Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/325794/261938) to make custom keyboard shortcuts doesn't work because gnome-screenshot still uses the dialog box by default.

I've already set the autosave location and the screen flash + shutter sound is enough of an indication that a shot's been taken so no need to argue pros and cons [like](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699276) [all](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=715038) [the](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=681844) [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=652487) [reports](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=669629) that do.

Is there a setting or some way to disable the dialog box from appearing while trying to keep Ubuntu light by not having to install more things as much as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `gnome-screenshot` has `-f` option to specify store file. The following command should be the replacement you are looking for:

  ```
  gnome-screenshot -f "$HOME/Pictures/Screenshot from $(date '+%F %T').png"
  ```
- One way! is to replace `gnome-screenshot` to be run with addition parameter:

  1. Move original:

     ```
     sudo mv /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot.orig
     ```
  2. Create a modified command:

     `sudo nano /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot.mod`

     ```
     #!/bin/sh
     gnome-screenshot.orig -f "$HOME/Pictures/Screenshot from $(date '+%F %T').png" $@
     ```

     Make it executable:

     ```
     sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot.mod
     ```
  3. Create replacement symbolic link:

     ```
     sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot.mod /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot
     ```

Comment: Thank you very much! The shutter sound doesn't play, but the screen flash should do. The `-f` option does the trick, plus you get to set the autosave location without needing the dconf editor. Athough, for #3, I had to switch the positions of `/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot` and `/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot.mod` in the command to make it work.